# Python - Plotly - sample code error (iplot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python

**Hello everyone,
My purpose is to run the below plotly sample code and save the output as HTML file on my hard drive.
Any idea for a go around?**

**When I run the code I get the following error:**

File "C:\Users\rbiberma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py", line 179, in request
raise exceptions.PlotlyRequestError(message, status_code, content)

PlotlyRequestError: No message

**The error is triggered by the code line: **py.iplot(fig1, filename='table-right-aligned-plots')****

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

table_trace1 = go.Table(
    domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5],
                y=[0, 1.0]),
    columnwidth = [30] + [33, 35, 33],
    columnorder=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    header = dict(height = 50,
                  values = [['<b>Date</b>'],['<b>Number<br>transactions</b>'],
                            ['<b>Output<br>volume(BTC)</b>'], ['<b>Market<br>Price</b>']],
                  line = dict(color='rgb(50, 50, 50)'),
                  align = ['left'] * 5,
                  font = dict(color=['rgb(45, 45, 45)'] * 5, size=14),
                  fill = dict(color='#d562be')),
    cells = dict(values = [df[k].tolist() for k in
                          ['Date', 'Number-transactions', 'Output-volume(BTC)', 'Market-price']],
                 line = dict(color='#506784'),
                 align = ['left'] * 5,
                 font = dict(color=['rgb(40, 40, 40)'] * 5, size=12),
                 format = [None] + [", .2f"] * 2 + [',.4f'],
                 prefix = [None] * 2 + ['$', u'\u20BF'],
                 suffix=[None] * 4,
                 height = 27,
                 fill = dict(color=['rgb(235, 193, 238)', 'rgba(228, 222, 249, 0.65)']))
)

trace1=go.Scatter(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=df['Hash-rate'],
    xaxis='x1',
    yaxis='y1',
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(width=2, color='#9748a1'),
    name='hash-rate-TH/s'
)

trace2=go.Scatter(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=df['Mining-revenue-USD'],
    xaxis='x2',
    yaxis='y2',
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(width=2, color='#b04553'),
    name='mining revenue'
)

trace3=go.Scatter(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=df['Transaction-fees-BTC'],
    xaxis='x3',
    yaxis='y3',
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(width=2, color='#af7bbd'),
    name='transact-fee'
)

axis=dict(
    showline=True,
    zeroline=False,
    showgrid=True,
    mirror=True,
    ticklen=4,
    gridcolor='#ffffff',
    tickfont=dict(size=10)
)

layout1 = dict(
    width=950,
    height=800,
    autosize=False,
    title='Bitcoin mining stats for 180 days',
    margin = dict(t=100),
    showlegend=False,
    xaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.55, 1], anchor='y1', showticklabels=False)),
    xaxis2=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.55, 1], anchor='y2', showticklabels=False)),
    xaxis3=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.55, 1], anchor='y3')),
    yaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.66, 1.0], anchor='x1', hoverformat='.2f')),
    yaxis2=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.3 + 0.03, 0.63], anchor='x2', tickprefix='$', hoverformat='.2f')),
    yaxis3=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.0, 0.3], anchor='x3', tickprefix=u'\u20BF', hoverformat='.2f')),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(228, 222, 249, 0.65)'
)

fig1 = dict(data=[table_trace1, trace1, trace2, trace3], layout=layout1)
plotly.offline.plot(fig1, filename="table-right-aligned-plots")
```

**The desired output:**

[image]

Answer:

py.iplot(fig1, filename='table-right-aligned-plots')

Should be replaced with: plotly.offline.plot(fig1, filename="table-right-aligned-plots")

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a way to take what isn't HTML and make it such. [Plotly's documentation](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) doesn't list it as an option. You could export the static image in any of a number of ways (you'll note png, webp, jpeg and are built-in, amongst other options). You could also look at [kaleido](https://pypi.org/project/kaleido/) to see if that does what approximately what you need.

But perhaps what you really need is a different graphing library like Plotly's Dash.